# How to perform read data from file, then validate data and insert data in to Database operations asynchronously

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, asynchronous

I have the following three methods in my Windows service for transforming CSV data files to Sql server database.

- Method 1: For reading data from a CSV file (each row contains one Employee data)
- Method 2: For validating data by Employee Id,Name etc.
- Method 3: For inserting data in to a database table.

Currently, I am reading one row from the CSV file and calling the above 3 methods one by one (meaning after completing method 1 I will start method 2 and after completing method 2 I will start method 3. Then again I will read another row from the CSV file and repeat the same steps)

As this is a synchronous process it is taking long time to process one file with more then ten thousands of records.

If I want to make this an asynchronous process, how would I call my methods asynchronously, and what C# classes should I use to achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming the order of insert doesn't matter?

Comment: Just change your approach first read csv insert full data into a table then valid the data of whole table and insert onto main table this will improve the performance

Comment: Yeah, the order of insert doesn't matter.

Comment: But if i do validation after inserting in to database, then I need to delete the invalid data. That again needs database operations.

Comment: You could do this in SSIS quite easily if you're interested in that.

Comment: But that doesn't cost you more in terms of.time and read write operation

Answer (score 1):

To do so the best is to create your Class in the code make a List of your class, on validation add the validated data in this list and the non validated you can put them in a string or another list to show that the rest weren't inserted.

The List of accepted Employees

```
public List<Employee> acceptedEmployees = new List<Employee>();
```

The Employee class

```
class Employee {
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }

   public Employee(int ID, string name)
        {
           ID = ID;
           Name = name;
        }
}
```

In the loop you can add them to the list, and then create a batch insert from this list or make logs as well or send them back to the client.

When your adding the batch to the database make sure to use 1 Connection to insert everything do not connect on each insert batch that can make your system slow.

After the list is done, you can create a batch insert of 500 per statement for example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, NAME) VALUES (1,'Dan'),(2,'Stack'),(3,'Whatever');
```

When all your queries are ready you can run them in sequence.

Comment: batch insert, nice touch!

Comment: CtrlDot, I had the same issue weeks ago it was with Java but the same concept... I came with the batch insert and same connection which made gave me 80% speed improvement so i hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\employees.csv")

List<Task> tasks = new List<Tasks>();

foreach(var line in csvLines )
{//spawn tasks to parse, validate , save
   var task = Task<ValidationResult>.Factory.StartNew(()=>
     {//async task start

         var validationResult = Validate(line);
         if(validationResult.IsValid)
         {
            Save(validationResult.Employee);
         }     

         return validationResult; 

     });//async task end

     tasks.Add(task);

}

//wait for results
var allResults = new List<ValidationResult>();    
foreach(var t in tasks)
{
 allResults.Add(t.Result);
}
```

Comment: If i have 1,00,000 rows in my text file, does File.ReadAllLines() methods blocks my system RAM?

Comment: It should be ok, I used it before in a very similar situation, if you are concerned about memory usage, you could still use a file stream, and consume each line one by one. The idea is once you have a line from the csv file in whichever read method, you go ahead and start an async task that validates and inserts that records in the database.